# Rails routing error when using resource but now when using GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am creating a simple suggestion box app (to learn Rails) and am getting the following Rails routing error when I go to "/suggestion-boxes" running on my local machine (localhost:3000)

"**Routing Error**

No route matches [GET] "/suggestion-boxes"

In my routes.rb file I have:

```ruby
SuggestionBoxApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :suggestion_boxes
end
```

This is what I get when I run rake routes:

```ruby
suggestion-box-app$ rake routes
suggestion_boxes GET    /suggestion_boxes(.:format)          suggestion_boxes#index
                POST   /suggestion_boxes(.:format)          suggestion_boxes#create
new_suggestion_box GET    /suggestion_boxes/new(.:format)      suggestion_boxes#new
edit_suggestion_box GET    /suggestion_boxes/:id/edit(.:format) suggestion_boxes#edit
 suggestion_box GET    /suggestion_boxes/:id(.:format)      suggestion_boxes#show
                PUT    /suggestion_boxes/:id(.:format)      suggestion_boxes#update
                DELETE /suggestion_boxes/:id(.:format)      suggestion_boxes#destroy
```

However, if I modify my routes file to

```ruby
SuggestionBoxApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "suggestion-boxes" => "suggestion_boxes#index"
end
```

Then the page "/suggestion-boxes" displays as per the index action in my SuggestionBoxesController.

I tried restarting my server but this had no impact. While I of course can go with using GET, this error makes no sense, and I would like understand what is causing it.

Any insights would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you are calling to `suggestion-boxes` controller which does not exist. Your controller is `suggestion_boxes`, spelling. So where every you have "suggestion-boxes" you should replace with "`suggestion_boxes`". The code that you added create an alias that matches '`suggestion-boxes`' to the `index` action of the `suggestion_boxes` controller so this resolves it if it is your desired affect. But simply fixing your spelling would resolve your problem. I usually use the second approach if I want the change the URL that user see. Have a look at the [routing doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for a better understanding

Comment: Hadn't even noticed that I was using dashes in one place and underscores in another - lesson learned! Thanks!

Comment: @andersr No problem, it happens

Answer (score 2):

The error is that you are not renaming the REST route, instead the controller one.
Try declaring

```
resources :suggestion_boxes, :as => "suggestion-boxes"
```

in your `config/routes.rb` file.